# SVM classifier- save the trained model

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, svm

I am new in machine learning. I am using SGDClassifier to classify my documents. I trained the model. To persist the trained data I used pickle

code in classify.py for training model

```
corpus=df2.title_desc  #df2 is my dataframe with 2 columns title_desc and category
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix=vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).todense()

variables = tfidf_matrix
labels = df2.category

variables_train, variables_test, labels_train, labels_test  =   train_test_split(variables, labels, test_size=0.1)

svm_classifier=linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',alpha=0.0001)

svm_classifier=svm_classifier.fit(variables_train, labels_train)

with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(svm_classifier, fid)
```

After the data is dumped to a file.I created another py file to test the model

test.py

```
corpus_test=df_test.title_desc  #df_testis my dataframe with 2 columns title_desc and category


 vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

tfidf_matrix_test=vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus_test).todense()

svm_classifier=linear_model.SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',alpha=0.0001)


with open('my_dumped_classifier.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
    svm_classifier = pickle.load(fid)   

tfidf_matrix_test=vectorizer.transform(corpus_test).todense()
svm_predictions=svm_classifier.predict(tfidf_matrix_test)
```

I am not sure about the logic I have give in test.py. In line

```
svm_predictions=svm_classifier.predict(tfidf_matrix_test)
```

its an error 'ValueError: X has 249 features per sample; expecting 1050'

Please give a solution.

Comment: This might be because the number of features used while training the model is 1050. So, the dumped model is expecting 1050 features while your test data has 249 features.